# Rails Error - undefined local variable or method `signout_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The error is from  app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb. That piece of line is part of my app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb whic is the following:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">


       <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
          <% if signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
            <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Account <b class="caret"></b>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                  <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li> 
         <% end %>        
        </ul>  
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: in your shell run 

    `rake routes`

to see how your routes are named.

Comment: can you put your routes.rb file?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's getting late here and i don't wait for your output of rake routes or routes.rb file. 
As mentioned in my comment, got to your shell, cd to your application directory and run

```
rake routes
```

this will display all possible routes. Chances are, that there's already a route for the sign out process.

If not, you have to create the route in your /config/routes.rb and direct it to the right controller. For example

```
delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'
```

where 'delete' is the request, '/logout' my example url, 'sessions' the controller and 'destroy' it's action and 'signout' your method name (as you wished it in your code). 
you can just write

```
delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
```

in this case, you have to replace your method-name `signout_path` for example with the url.

One last hint: Logging out can be done, too with GET instead of DELETE. Maybe you created a route with only the GET method? Should be obvious in the output of `rake routes`, too.